# halvetica bold @font face not working in chrome and safari in mac

Tags: html, css, font-face

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'helvetica-bold';  
  src: url("../fonts/helvetica-bold.ttf");     /* IE */
  src: local('helvetica-bold'),     url('../fonts/helvetica-bold.ttf') format('truetype'); /* others */    
}
```

I am using the  font in my site but  its not working in mac   any one help greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `woff` and `svg` font type as well.

Comment: It should work, but your question isn't constructive enough for an answer. What browser are you using? "Mac" doesn't say anything. What is the status on the fonts in developer tools? Is the path correct? Are you using `font-family:'helvetica-bold', sans-serif;` in your CSS? Where are your `.woff` and `.svg` files? `.ttf` is widely supported, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try helvetica-bold.eot, .woff and .svg font along with .ttf in font-face.

There are many sites which are converting .ttf font to .eot and other types (you can google it)

so your new code will be -

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'helvetica-bold';
 src: url('helvetica-bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
 src: url('helvetica-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('helvetica-bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
   url('helvetica-bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('helvetica-bold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to add custom font for `Helvetica`, cause its a `web safe font`. You just need to add following `css`.

```
body{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```